# Dynamically Evaluate load and create Threads depending on machine performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, distributed-computing

Hi i have started to work on a project where i use parallel computing to separate job loads among multiple machines, such as hashing and other forms of mathematical calculations. Im using C++

it is running on a Master/slave or Server/Client model if you prefer where every client connects to the server and waits for a job. The server can than take a job and seperate it depending on the number of clients

```
 1000 jobs   -- > 3 clients
 IE: client 1 --> calculate(0 to 333)
     Client 2 --> calculate(334 to 666)
     Client 3 --> calculate(667 to 999)
```

I wanted to further enhance the speed by creating multiple threads on every running client. But since every machine are not likely (almost 100%) not going to have the same hardware, i cannot arbitrarily decide on a number of threads to run on every client.

i would like to know if one of you guys knew a way to evaluate the load a thread has on the cpu and extrapolate the number of threads that can be run concurently on the machine.

there are ways i see of doing this.

1. I start threads one by one, evaluating the cpu load every time and stop when i reach a certain prefix ceiling of (50% - 75% etc) but this has the flaw that ill have to stop and re-separate the job every time i start a new thread.
2. (and this is the more complex)
   run some kind of test thread and calculate its impact on the cpu base load and extrapolate the number of threads that can be run on the machine and than start threads and separate jobs accordingly.

any idea or pointer are welcome, thanks in advance !

Comment: [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency)

Comment: Arent task dependent on the previous task output or completion ?

Comment: Great question - Why don't you want to push the CPU to 100% ? - you could lower the priority..

Comment: well depending on the machine, i might be doing other things on it so maybe i dont want to use ALL of the cpu power on that machine, for example

Comment: For true concurrency on Client `NumberOfThreadOnClient = NumberOfCoreOnClient`. Any thing more than that will have to wait unless the work performed by a thread is `I/O`. Also please specify what kind of work is expected to be done by thread.

Comment: I mentioned it in the first paragraph, at first i want to start simple so ill have it do some hashing, but i intend to refine the process to have it do others types of mathematical and parallel work